# Need of a subject after 'and' conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, correlative-conjunctions

Sometimes i see "She went there and she started working." And often i see "She went there and started working."
should I use the subject again after 'and' or not? What is the rule? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As DW256 says in his answer below, your examples are coordinate constructions consisting respectively of two main clauses and two verb phrases: [She went there] and she started working]. / She [went there] and [started working]. The second one is semantically equivalent to the first, but far more stylistically elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically acceptable. The relation between the elements is called coordination.

In one case it would be a coordination of main clauses:

> [She went there][and[she started working]].

In the other case it would be of verb phrases:

> She [went there][and[started working]].

Leaving the repeated element in tends to emphasize it.

Comment: Thanks...can you tell which one is preferable and why?

Comment: Neither one is preferable. It depends on how verbose the speaker wants to be.